# Finding a formula for a series/sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help with finding a formula for the following sequence:

$3$rd term = $2.03$

$4$th term = $3.06$

$5$th term = $4.11$

$6$th term = $5.18$

I'm not trying to find what comes before or after, only a formula for this part of the sequence.

I have some general ideas like $n-1$ for the whole numbers, but its the decimals that I'm unsure of. If it was the 1st 2nd 3rd and 4th term it wouldn't have been that difficult since it would have been something like $(n-1)+((n^2-2)/100)$. However, since its the 3rd 4th 5th and 6th terms, I don't know how to set up a formula

Comment: $.01n^2+.96n-.94$ works.  All I did was fit it via Lagrange Interpolation and discarded the negligible cubic term (which has to be a numerical artifact).  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polynomialinterpolation%5B%283%2C2.03%29%2C%284%2C3.06%29%2C%285%2C4.11%29%2C%286%2C5.18%29%5D) can do it.

Comment: Lookup [“polynomial interpolation”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation) – or simply use Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+%5B%283%2C+2.03%29%2C%284%2C+3.06%29%2C%285%2C+4.11%29%2C+%286%2C+5.18%29%5D

Comment: If it's the decimal places that are bothering you, you can just multiply each value by $100$. Then at the end, you divide your solution by $100$.

Comment: You almost got it, just shift $n$ by $2$ in $n^2+2$, so your formula becomes $(n-1)+((n-2)^2+2)/100$.